# Use a name for prefix discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

how can I use the bot name as a space prefix to use a command?

```
 let prefix = 'test '; //botconfig.prefix;
  let messageArray = message.content.split(" ")
  let cmd = messageArray[0].toLowerCase();
  let args = messageArray.slice(1);
  if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
  let commandfile = bot.commands.get(cmd.slice(prefix.length)) || bot.commands.get(bot.aliases.get(cmd.slice(prefix.length)))
  if(commandfile) commandfile.run(bot, message, args);
```

Comment: I'm slightly confused. Are you saying you want the prefix to be mentioning the bot, i.e. `@bot dosomething`?

Comment: for example : bot play x, bot ban y, bot mute z with prefix (bot and space)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like this?

You want to use the bot username as the prefix, so you can use `message.client.user`.

Then for your arguments, I tweaked it a little.

This is how each variable indexes the argument.

```
//messageArray
bot do this
0   1  2
//args
bot do this
n/a 0  1
//n/a, because args sliced that element out.
```

It also looks like messageArray just exists for the sole purpose of helping args, so you can make your code this:

```js
  let prefix = message.client.user.username.toLowerCase();
  let args = message.content.split(/\s+/).slice(1);
  if(!message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix)) return;
  let commandfile = bot.commands.get(args[0].toLowerCase()) || 
  bot.commands.get(bot.aliases.get(args[0].toLowerCase()));
  if(commandfile) commandfile.run(bot, message, args);
```

I added some `toLowerCase`s because if the bot finds something like `BOT`, and it does `if("BOT".startsWith("bot")`, it returns `false`, basically so the command isn't case sensitive.

Make sure your bot name doesn't have spaces, or you may have to change the indexes a little bit, or remove spaces from the username.

You can always refer to the docs [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome).